# Does Computrace work on *NIX like systems?

Tags: linux, bios

I've done tons of research on `Computrace` from **Absolute Software** and I haven't found a solid answer to: Does it work on Linux?

I've read the following research papers and they don't refer to Linux or *NIX like systems once:

[Deactivate the Rootkit](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-09/ORTEGA/BHUSA09-Ortega-DeactivateRootkit-PAPER.pdf)

[Absolute Backdoor Revisited](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-Kamluk-Computrace-Backdoor-Revisited-WP.pdf)

They're all focused on reverse engineering the agents/binaries that are dropped onto Windows machines. I've looked at the running processes on multiple Linux systems with `Computrace` enabled and there isn't any sign of it. So I guess I've answered my own question, but for some reason I don't feel assured that it is 100% **NOT** working on Linux. If anyone here has experience with Computrace or has also tested themselves, please let me know!

Comment: As this is (was) a commercial product, you should ask the Absolute support.

Comment: "I've looked at the running processes on multiple Linux systems with Computrace enabled and there isn't any sign of it." this does not make sense. How is it enabled? And then how is it possible that, when enabled is there no sign of it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is asking for support of a proprietary product, that is not even written for Unix.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Its enabled from the BIOS. Also feel free to close this. I already got my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Computrace **CANNOT** work on a Linux system.  Even if it's enabled and triggered by Absolute Software it will never activate unless a Windows based OS is installed on the hard drive.

Computrace relies on injecting itself into `autochk.exe` to receive commands and start.  Even if the BIOS module is active and triggered before the Linux OS is installed it cannot operate as its communications with the C&C server is handled by a modified Windows component that is planted into the install.  Without this component computrace is as good as dead.

You can read up on it here, [Absolute Backdoor Revisited](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-Kamluk-Computrace-Backdoor-Revisited-WP.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

From a description I understand that Computrace uses a component that is basically build into the computer, and can not be removed. This component is active independent of what the computer does, including which operating system it runs. The component provides administrator access to support the advertised features of Computrace. It is delivered in an inactive state as part of the computer hardware, mostly as part of the firmware.

The build in component provides complex features, but it has no user interface. So there is a management software needed, that runs on the PC as normal program. The management software may be provided for Microsoft Windows only.

On a Linux PC, the user can not interact with the built in component, it is invisible. The basic idea of Computrace is to allow full takeover of the PC, and it can even do things the operating system can not. It is a high quality, professional built-in rootkit.

If it is activated, it can not be configured, but it can provide full remote control.
The intention is, of course, to give access only to Absolute Software. But if they can access it, it can be hacked, and used for hostile purposes.

So, on Linux, part of it works, and part of it does not. Only the part that can be hacked works, the user can not actually configure it for the intended purpose.

Whether it works depends on the perspective. From the perspective of a user of the PC, it does not work.

(It may be possible to use the Windows software for configuration, and otherwise use Linux)